# The Joy of Clojure: "rest vs. next" sample doesn't produce the same result in my REPL

Tags: clojure

Here is an extract from "The Joy of Clojure":

> What happens when you create a potentially infinite sequence of integers using
>   iterate, printing a dot each time you generate a new value, and then use either
>   rest or next to return the first three values of the sequence? The difference between
>   rest and next can be seen in the following example:
>
> (def very-lazy (-> (iterate #(do (print .) (inc %)) 1)
>   rest rest rest))
>   ;=> ..#'user/very-lazy
>
> (def less-lazy (-> (iterate #(do (print .) (inc %)) 1)
>   next next next))
>   ;=> ...#'user/less-lazy
>
> As shown, the next version printed three dots, whereas the rest version printed only
>   two. When building a lazy seq from another, rest doesn’t cause the calculation of
>   (or realize) any more elements than it needs to; next does. In order to determine
>   whether a seq is empty, next needs to check whether there’s at least one thing in
>   it, thus potentially causing one extra realization. Here’s an example:
>
> (println (first very-lazy)) ; .4
>
> (println (first less-lazy)) ; 4

Here is what I get in my "Cursive IDE" REPL:

```
(def very-lazy (-> (iterate #(do (print \.) (inc %)) 1)
               rest rest rest))
..=> #'user/very-lazy
(def less-lazy (-> (iterate #(do (print \.) (inc %)) 1)
               next next next))
..=> #'user/less-lazy
(println (first very-lazy)) ; .4
.4
=> nil
(println (first less-lazy)) ; 4
.4
=> nil
```

I think I do understand the explanation of the different behaviors, but why is the output the same in my REPL?

Comment: FWIW, I get the same behavior in a straight console `lein repl`, too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The implementation of `iterate` changed in Clojure 1.7.0. Prior to 1.7, it was implemented in terms of `cons` and `lazy-seq` and it exhibited the behaviour described in the fragment of JoC you quoted. Starting with 1.7, it is implemented in terms of a dedicated `clojure.lang.Iterate` class which handles `rest` and `next` in the same way, and so its behaviour is as you discovered at the REPL.

- [`(defn iterate …)` in Clojure 1.6.0.](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.6.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L2719)
- [`(defn iterate …)` in Clojure 1.7.0.](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.7.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L2882)
- [`public class Iterate …` in Clojure 1.7.0.](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.7.0/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Iterate.java)

Comment: Does this change within the `iterate` function negate the advice found in that section of the book, to always use rest over next when consuming sequences in the body of a `lazy-seq`?

Comment: I would think the advice would stand because `next` is still one item less lazy than `rest`.